# How to convert and revert this time to UNIX using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to save this date format into my DB 20/07/2012 22:10 in a UNIX format.
How can I do this, and how can I revert it to a readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for on of two possible variants.

```
//save it
$timestamp = strtotime('20/07/2012 22:10');
$timestamp = mktime(22, 10, 0, 20, 7, 2012); //mktime(h,m,s,M,D,Y)

//retrieve it with
while ($rows = /*...*/) { 
    $timestamp = date("D/M/Y g:i",$rows['timestamp']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. So I have cleared how to revert it through the `date("D/M/Y g:i",$rows['timestamp']);` but how do I convert a time that is not the current, like the one posted above?

Comment: I tried the conversion, however on an online converter to a readable format, the unix time was about 1 year later than the actual 20/07/2012

Comment: @Kaoukkos Which one did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Try the strtotime() PHP function. It is probably what you are looking for. To get it back to a readable format use the date() function like:

```
$date = date('Y-M-d', $unixTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

As David said, you can use `strtotime('20/07/2012 22:20')` but you'll have to be careful with the locale setting.

If you feel more confortable though, you can try this:

```
list($d, $m, $y, $h, $i) = sscanf('20/07/2012 22:20', '%d/%d/%d %d:%d');
$unix_timestamp = mktime($h, $i, 0, $m, $d, $y);
```

Comment: How can I add two hours on the result ?